# App launched from sandboxed app is not sandboxed

Tags: swift, macos, network-programming, sandbox, macos-catalina

I have an untrusted app on macOS that I want to run, but without allowing it to connect to the internet.

What is the best way to achieve this?

My best idea was to build a simplistic launch app in swift in xcode, and sandbox this launcher. From what I read, apps launched from sandboxed apps should themselves be sandboxed.

So my launcher app looks like this:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        NSWorkspace.shared.open("/path/inside/bundle/to/untrustedApp.app")
        print ("after")

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    }


}
```

(Note that I used `NSWorkspace.shared.open` because `NSWorkspace.shared.openApp` didn't do anything, not even call the completion handler.)

And I added the sandbox capability in xcode, and made sure all boxes where unchecked. Am I doing anything wrong? Or is my understanding off?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `NSTask` to directly launch the Mach-O executable inside the untrusted app:

- `NSTask` inherits the sandbox of the parent app (See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask))
- `NSTask` lets you specify the Mach-O executable, which is necessary because `untrusted.app` has it's own code signature, plist files, and entitlements (or lack thereof)

For example, the following trivial application will get the name of the Mach-O executable from:

```
/path/to/your/ParentApp.app/relative/path/to/Restricted.app
```

For example, for `firefox`:

```
/path/to/your/ParentApp.app/relative/path/to/Restricted.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

**Swift:**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    let theMainAppBundle = Bundle.main.bundlePath
    let theChildAppBundle = theMainAppBundle + ("/relative/path/to/RestrictedApp.app")
    let childBundleExecutable = Bundle(path: theChildAppBundle)?.executablePath
    Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: childBundleExecutable ?? "", arguments: [""])
    NSApp.terminate(self)

}
```

**Objective C:**

```
(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSString *theMainAppBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *theChildAppBundle = [theMainAppBundle stringByAppendingString:@"/relative/path/to/RestrictedApp.app"];
    NSString *childBundleExecutable = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:theChildAppBundle].executablePath;
    [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:childBundleExecutable arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
    [NSApp terminate:self];

}
```

Comment: Hey @hmedia1, thanks for that. Did you mean that I should first copy the untrusted app (for example firefox) inside my main app bundle? Also, the problem with this approach is that the executable of the untrusted app is sandboxed, but does not have the inherit entitlement that is necessary. So the child process will be aborted (NSTask requires the child app to have strictly 2 entitlements: sandbox and inherit, when launched from a sandboxed main app).

Comment: @DevShark, Hi I wasn't sure of your environment or requirements ... if this is a third party app, or one you have control of, etc... I assumed you had the freedom to copy files around since in your question you actually specified the untrusted app **would** be inside your main app bundle (__"`/path/inside/bundle/to/untrustedApp.app`"__)

Comment: @DevShark None the less, there's gotta be 100 ways of achieving what you want, but what are your constraints ?   You say the untrusted app **is** sandboxed, but doesn't have the inherit entitlement.  I have heard that helper apps need these two entitlements, but I must make helper apps wrong because it's never been an issue for me.

Comment: @DevShark Have you actually tried the launcher I posted ?  I've tried it with both sandboxed and unsandboxed apps, none of which have the inherit entitlement and all of which have many more than those explicit two entitlements.  Since at least I know you have control of the parent app, then why does this need to be sandboxed ?    **Sorry, I forgot to mention**, the code I posted runs an app without internet access, so long as the outgoing connections entitlement in the **Parent** app is turned off - This is what I thought you wanted ... to be able to control the child apps sandbox properties..

Comment: ..from the parent app

Comment: And even if you don't have control of the child app - you could still `codesign` it again however you like, even without your developer certificate.

Comment: @DevShark One more thought .. maybe your wrapper need be no more complex than just running `sandbox-exec -n no-internet /path/to/untrusted.app/Contents/MacOS/untrustedapp`

Comment: Hi @hmedia1, no problem with copying files around. Definitely fine to put the helper apps inside the mainApp. If the mainApp is sandboxed (which  we want, so that we can prevent the helper app from accessing the network), then the helper app needs strictly only the 2 entitlements. This is according to the doc, and this is what I saw when I tried previously, with code similar to you. However, it sounds like it works on your end. I will try again then with exactly your code. I’ll let you know soon how it looks. Thanks!

Comment: The sandbox-exec fails. By the way, I am trying this on macOS 10.15, if you’re on an holder version, that might explain why it works for you but not for me.

Comment: The helper app is a third party app, say for example /Applications/Safari.app

Comment: Ok, I tried again and this does not work. My guess is that either your main app is not sandboxed or your child app is not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204669/discussion-between-hmedia1-and-devshark).

Comment: @DevShark Did you get the alert of the chat ?